# SUDS - Exception: prefix (xs) not resolved

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, soap, suds

### I try this:

```
from suds.client import Client

client = Client("http://sandbox.soapservice.com/ags/1.5/server.php?wsdl")

Message = client.factory.create('xs:anyType')
```

### This is the response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 216, in create
    type = self.resolver.find(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/resolver.py", line 108, in find
    result = self.root(parts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/resolver.py", line 130, in root
    qref = self.qualify(parts[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/resolver.py", line 193, in qualify
    return qualify(name, self.wsdl.root, self.wsdl.tns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/xsd/__init__.py", line 46, in qualify
    raise Exception('prefix (%s) not resolved' % p)
Exception: prefix (xs) not resolved
```

### this is the method for the service:

```
Rotulos_tiempoTranscurrido(xs:anyType tiempo)
```

## how can I create this in suds?